# Too early for minimum SDK 2.2? Need Push

Tags: android

Is it too early to require minimum version 2.2 from my users?

I definitely need Push Notifications for my app and, while I have crawled through the stackoverflow topics and know there are a few options out there - such as MQTT which seems to be popular, I think using Google's C2DMA is going to be the easiest route..

So, do you guys think it is too easy to require this version? My app is a general-use messenger, similar to skype, msn, etc (but obviously with some unique twists, not competing with them at all, its a local audience I am servicing).

Hmm..

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a purely business perspective, get the app into the wild with the 2.2 requirement and play it by ear as to whether app interest is high enough to not bother with the manual implementation.

If you don't get much interest, perhaps then go down the lesser requirements front.

Looking at the [version demographic](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) provided by the other answers, from a development perspective, I think you are fairly safe to go with 2.2 as you would only be "losing out" on 7-8%.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) document to realize how many users will be unable to run your application if you will require the Android 2.2 as a minimum version. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you won't loose a lot of user when you require 2.2. When I check the stats of my app, I see this:

Android 2.3.3+
56.87 %

Android 2.2
14.75 %

Android 4.0.3
4.65 %

Android 3.2
4.44 %

Android 2.1
2.75 %

Android 3.1
2.18 %

Android 4.0
0.84 %

Android 2.3
0.39 %

Android 1.6
0.39 %

Others
12.74 %

(My minimum is 1.6 by the way)